# Como executar uma user story grande ou como dividi-la

Tags: metodologia-ágil, scrum

Sou novo nessa metodologia, e estou diversos problemas com a seguinte `user story`:

**1 Como gerente da loja, eu gostaria de cadastrar um produto para que ele possa ser vendido.**

E nos detalhes do cartão, eu coloquei alguns requisitos como:

- O nome do produto deve ter até 50 caracteres
- O produto possui uma categoria
- O produto possui um preço de custo
- O produto possui um preço de venda
- etc...

Porém, essa user story parece grande demais, pois contempla:

1. A criação da interface do usuário;
2. A criação da tabela no banco de dados;
3. A criação da classe produto;
4. A criação do repositório
5. A criação de uma factory;
6. Tratamento de possíveis erros (ex: limitar o campo até 50 caracteres, verificar se o usuário especificou alguma categoria para o produto, etc...)

Me complica mais ainda, que nessa user story há campos para preço de custo e margem de lucro, o que me gerou uma nova user story:

**2 Como gerente, eu gostaria de poder fornecer um preço de custo, para que a partir dele eu possa calcular o lucro e definir o preço de venda**

Sei que poderia tentar quebrar a user story em menores, mas acho que seria ***incorreto*** algo como:

**Como gerente, eu gostaria que houvesse uma tela para cadastro de produtos, para que eu possa cadastrar os produtos**

**Como gerente, eu gostaria que houvesse um espaço no banco de dados, para armazenar os produtos que eu criar**

Como então eu quebro essa função? Como eu divido as tarefas para a equipe? Se eu quebrar a user story em outras menores, eu devo deletar a *pai* que gerou elas?

**Justificativa da resposta**

Pra quem tiver interesse, vou justificar por que eu aceitei essa resposta. Eu tentei fazer o que o @Rodrigo Guiotti falou. A solução era essa mesmo, quebrar a user story em menores, só precisei ter um pouco de criatividade como foi sugerido. Quebrei em partes como: cadastrar...

1. dados básicos;
2. lucro;
3. dados fiscais;

Dessa forma consegui dividir bem as tarefas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você sabe o remédio já na sua pergunta. Realmente precisa dividir os épicos de uma forma que faça sentido para você e para o seu time.
Mas a divisão que você propôs não ajuda muito e se você pretende definir exatamente como vai ser a solução, dificilmente você vai conseguir ficar só com as histórias de usuário e partir para Casos de Uso.

O principal para uma história ser dividida é a estimativa total ficar em mais de uma ou duas semanas de desenvolvimento. A lista de coisas que você sugeriu, não parece que ficaria tão grande assim, mas infelizmente não existe uma regra simples de quebrar.

Vai precisar de criatividade, principalmente no início. Depois pega o jeito.

Comece perguntando ao seu time como eles fariam para fazer esse trabalho, por onde eles começariam a desenvolver e se perguntem se não é possível quebrar a história ali.

Para ajudar, vou tentar dar um exemplo. Imagina como você gostaria de dividir o  trabalho em duas pessoas. Que você acha que uma pessoa deve fazer a interface gráfica e outra deve fazer o banco de dados. Nesse caso você poderia dividir assim e desassociar o banco de dados da interface:

“Como gerente, quero ter o cadastro de todos os produtos e seus preços de custo para que eu possa posteriormente calcular o lucro e definir o preço de venda.” - BD
“Como gerente, quero poder adicionar produtos ao cadastro usando uma tela, sem precisar de linhas de comandos para diminuir as falhas humanas possíveis e agilizar o trabalho.” - GUI
“Como gerente, quero poder fazer visualizar os produtos cadastrados, calcular o lucro e definir o preço de venda em uma tela para visualizar os resultados de forma simples e que possa comunicar para outras pessoas da empresa.” - GUI

---

Quanto a última pergunta, se é melhor apagar a história para não ter histórias repetidas ou não... Depende da organização de vocês e para você ter controle melhor do que foi pedido e realizado de fato, costuma valer a pena olhar apenas para as histórias filhas, já que são essas que estão sendo planejadas e desenvolvidas.

Mas para saber se você atendeu todo o backlog, faz sentido olhar para as histórias pai, pode ser que a divisão em diversas histórias ainda não atenda totalmente a história original e ter a lista de histórias originais para confirmar que atenderam bem pode ajudar. Se não estiverem atendendo bem, o problema ainda está na divisão das histórias.

Comment: Deu uma excelente esclarecida. Obrigado! Vou aguardar mais possibilidades de respostas para fazer uma análise crítica e eleger a melhor solução.

Answer (score 2):

tudo bom?

Excelente tópico. Mas antes de pensar em dividir ou não a história primeiro é importante a gente entender o real valor dela. 
Toda User Story é composta por **3W** - **Who** (quem), **What** (o que) e **Why** (porque). Sendo que é no Why que está o valor de negócio, aquilo que realmente vai gerar valor para o usuário.

Então vamos refletir na sua primeira história:

> 1 Como gerente da loja, eu gostaria de cadastrar um produto para que ele possa ser vendido.

Será que se eu chegar ao final da minha Sprint e entregar para o meu cliente uma tabela de banco de dados, por exemplo.

Será que esse nosso entregável gerou valor para o meu cliente?
Agora, será que ao final de uma Sprint, o cliente com uma tabela de banco de dados irá conseguir que o produto seja vendido ?

Bem, provavelmente não. Se eu não consigo gerar valor para o meu cliente com um fragmento de história, não faz sentido ter esse fragmento, ou seja, a história **Como gerente da loja, eu gostaria de cadastrar um produto para que ele possa ser vendido.** é o mínimo viável da minha entrega.

Para entender melhor vamos pensar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As suas entregas devem ter um pensamento vertical e não horizontal, pois é pensando verticalmente, como na imagem, que você estará entregando valor ao seu cliente.

Quando se deparar em como analisar se uma User Story é boa ou não, pense na seguinte técnica. O conceito de **INVEST**:

**I** Independent: sua história é independe de outras ?

**N** Negociable: sua história é algo negociável com seu cliente ?

**V** Valuable: sua história gera valor ao seu cliente ?

**E** Estimable: sua história é estimável ?

**S** Small: sua história é pequena ?

**T** Testable: sua história é testável ?

Se sua história atender as perguntas do conceito de INVEST, você tem uma história de qualidade. Sendo bem mais específico a sua história atende perfeitamente o conceito.

Porém, vejo que você está preocupado com as várias tarefas que são necessárias para então concluir e entregar a User Story. Isso é natural, e se for muito, pegue só uma história mesmo. 
Com o tempo e experiência com este e outros tipos de histórias você e sua equipe vão ganhando velocidade e irão entregar cada vez mais.

Answer (score 1):

Uma "User Story" pode e deve ser dividida quando necessário. Respeitando o conceito INVEST citado pelo colega na resposta anterior, vou tentar exemplificar de forma bem simples:

A "User Story" é baseada no conceito de cartões, ou seja, cada "User Story" é escrita em um cartão contendo o ator (quem quer) a ação (o que ele quer) e a funcionalidade (qual o resultado esperado).

Imagine um cartão, no tamanho padrão de um cartão de visita. Sua "User Story" cabe neste cartão? Se sua resposta foi não, então você precisa sim dividi-la.

Não confunda "User Story" com especificação funcional.

Sugiro leitura deste artigo:
http://blog.myscrumhalf.com/2011/10/user-stories-o-que-sao-como-usar/